# Qcubed 2.xx How do you extend the year range in the Qdatepicker dropdown

Tags: qcubed

We are working with a CMS system built with qCubed 2.xx   The Year range in the QDatepicker dropdown ended at year 2020.   I cannot seem to find where to set or extend the date year range.  Is there nyone out there who can help?
Thanks
David

Answer (score 0):

Glad to see someone else still using qcubed 2.xx :-)

Try to check this file:

```
includes/qcubed/_core/base_controls/QDateTimePicker.class.php
```

Look for these lines:

```
protected $intMinimumYear = 
protected $intMaximumYear =
```

Comment: Yes we have a whole bunch of CMS sites running on Qcubed.  I upgraded some but not many to 3.x and now there is a 4.0   Guess I better take some time to upgrade.  I am so glad we met up.  Thanks..I'll try the the stuff you sent.